# Ubuntu 15.10 npm error install phonegap

Tags: 15.10, nodejs, npm

I upgraded to 15.10 and installed Nodejs v5.8.0 and npm 3.7.3 then:

on terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

output:

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/usr/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-14a43b5b
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-14a43b5b' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-14a43b5b' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/frandmg/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

I have no problem with Ionic and cordova, but I need phonegap for the android developer app.

Any help?

thanks in advance.

PS: The log file is here: https://justpaste.it/sbhw

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened but I fixed with:

```
sudo npm remove -g phonegap

npm cache clean

sudo npm install -g phonegap@latest
```